# Train Darknet on 2 classes, but mAP goes down?

Tags: yolo, darknet

I'm trying to train the darknet with AlexeyAB fork on two image sets (face and hands), both are quite big >2000 images, about 1000x600 resolution in average. But after some training mAP drastically goes down. Looks like one of the classes gets "trained out":
[mAPdown.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnzIS.png)

Configured as guided: classes=2, filters=21, cfg:

```
[net]
# Testing
# batch=1
# subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=16
width=512
height=512
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 10000
policy=steps
steps=8000,9000
scales=.1,.1
```

As result (based on some variations, I've tried 416 as size and different pre-trained weights) either hands disappear:
[nohands.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blJji.jpg)
or faces:
[noface.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM5oi.jpg)

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Same problem here. Did you solve it?

Comment: As it turns out, in your dataset if you have two objects you have to mark them everywhere.  So you cannot just take hands dataset and face dataset and combine them into one.  
To get it working I had to cross mark everything first, then manually check... which is kinda tedious.